# Number formatting in labels in ggplot2?

Tags: r

I tried to format the labels that appears above of each column. I want them to have a thousand separator. It could be a comma or a point.

This is the code that I have tried.

```
df%>%
  group_by(Hour)%>%
  summarize(TotalValue= round(sum(Value)/1000000))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Hour, y = TotalValue, fill = "coral4"))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(7,22,1))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)+
  geom_col()+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = TotalValue),
                   box.padding   = 0.35,
                   point.padding = 0.5,
                   segment.color = 'grey50')
```

[This is plot the plot generated by the previous code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11H0V.png)

What I want is, for example, in the third column (valor = 37692) the number should has this format 36,792

Comment: Maybe `label = prettyNum(TotalValue, big.mark = ",")`

Comment: Or have a look at the scales package, e.g. `label = scales::number(TotalValue, big.mark = ",")` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `format()` function. An example:

```
labels <- c(43252, 54326, 54325)
format(labels, big.mark = ',', scientific = FALSE)
#> [1] "43,252" "54,326" "54,325"
```

In your example it would become:

```
df%>%
  group_by(Hour)%>%
  summarize(TotalValue= round(sum(Value)/1000000))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Hour, y = TotalValue, fill = "coral4"))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(7,22,1))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)+
  geom_col()+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = format(TotalValue, 
                                      big.mark = ',',
                                      scientific = FALSE)),
                   box.padding   = 0.35,
                   point.padding = 0.5,
                   segment.color = 'grey50')
```

You can use `?format` to read more.